# LLVM Insert function call defined from another file

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to insert a function all before a certain instruction but the function call is defined in another file. I tried

```
IRBuilder<> Builder(pi);
CallInst *callOne = Builder.CreateCall(func_ins, "foo");
```

where `func_ins` is `Function*`(or `Value*` to be more general) and `foo` is the variable name prefix of calling function got assigned.
Since this function is defined in another file I've no idea where the pointer `func_ins` should point to so I just set it to **NULL** but it didn't work.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to resolve this problem?

One more issue is can I use `WriteBitcodeToFile` to dump the instrumented code which has external function call to file because I‘m wondering it may report `Referencing function in another module` or `Broken Module` while performing module checking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may only call a function from the same `Module`, and you may not use `NULL` as the callee.

If the function is defined in another module, you need to first *declare* it in the module in which you want to make the call, then make the call using the declaration.

To declare it, create an identical function in the new module (via [Function::Create](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a6b78e0f5ec53ac05826d6cce648bca30)) and just don't assign it a body.

Comment: Thanks and here's part of sample code I'm using, I assume that Int1 represents for bool.`FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getInt1Ty(getGlobalContext()), false);
Value* func_ins = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "ExternalFunc", Mod);` remaining builder part is the same as in the question

Comment: Could you please give me some hints on how to pass function parameters as well? By `FunctionType::get` method there is one argument called `ArrayRef<Type *>` and I guess it is used to pass arguments. What should I do if I want to pass three parameters(say **int**, **float*** and **user defined struct***) into it?

Comment: @MinGao just check out [ArrayRef's constructors](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ArrayRef.html), there's a variety of ways to create one - including from an array and from an `std::vector`.