# Add functions to LLVM module we JIT from

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

Currently I'm trying to use a `llvm::ExecutionEngine` to JIT `llvm::Function`'s I generated lazily through my code generator one after another.

The content of some functions depend on the evaluation of others which means some functions need to be ready for execution in the JIT whereas others aren't generated yet.

This results in a directed acyclic code generation graph:

```
func_1 ---> func_2 (depends on fn1)
    \
     \-> func_3 -> func_4 (depends on func_1 and func_3)

time -------------->
```

All functions theoretically belong to the same compilation unit,
and shall be returned as one `llvm::Module` the **amalgamation**.

Is it possible somehow to feed the ExecutionEngine with new functions without adding a module (`engine->addModule(...);`) with forward declaration every time I want to add a new function to the JIT (which basically means 1 module for every function when generating recursively)?

Because then I would have to clone all functions through `llvm::CloneFunctionInto` into the amalgamation (or generate it again) which doesn't look like a good solution for me.

Comment: Is there a single place in the code where you finally force JIT compilation of a module (with e.g. `getFunctionAddress`)? If so, then you can add functions to a single `llvm::Module` instead, and then after all functions are generated, finally add that module to `llvm::ExecutionEngine`.

Comment: Denis, did you find a clean way to resolve this issue? I wonder if this is enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331498/llvm-insert-function-call-defined-from-another-file I mean, it probably works, but I wonder whether LLVM can do some neat optimizations in this case (e.g. inline).